# JavaScript: How to send HTTP post requests on a key-bind

Tags: javascript, html, post

I am new to HML and JavaScript and would like to know how to send a HTTP post request upon pressing a key for example 'w', in order to control a python based robot.

I've looked on google and researched the individual components of the question but failed to even make the key-binds even change attributes about the page, including the background.

My code is currently

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
 <head>
  <title>Rover</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script>
    $(document).keypress(function(e){
      if(e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 87){
        alert('UP');
      }
    });
  </script>
  <img src = /stream.mjpg>
 </body>
</html>
```

Where stream.jpg is a live feed from a camera.

The code should send a HTTP post to the server, in which python will detect (the server uses pythons `http.server`), which will control the motors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing that you're using JQuery, you could issue a POST request via the [`$.post()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method in your `keypress()` handler like this:

```html
<!-- Include JQuery library before script block -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--
To host file locally, download the js file above (at cloudflare URL) to
the same directory that your HTML is hosted from on your PI, and then
use this script block instead (and remove the cloudflare one above)
<script src="/jquery.min.js"></script>
-->

<body>
  <script>
    /* 
    Replace server url with actual hostname/ip and port of 
    your python server 
    */
    var SERVER_URL = "http://localhost:8080/";

    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
    
      if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 87) {
        /* 
        If shift + w key combination, issue POST request to 
        server running at address 
        */
        $.post(SERVER_URL);
        
        console.log("Shift + w detected");
      }
    });
  </script>
  <img src="/stream.jpg">
</body>
```

Comment: I'll try this however what do I need to change the SERVER_URL to as I'm running this on a raspberry pi, accessing the stream in the browser using `http://raspberrypi.local:8000/stream.mjpg` for testing the stream

Comment: And, can I download the cloud flare script to the rover so i can use the rover without an internet connection?

Comment: Ok - did you need help extending the script in so that is automatically reloads the JPG from your PI? I can show you how this can be done in the same JavaScript if you'd like? Also, yes you can pull the JQuery library from CloudFlare if your host has internet access

Comment: The Pi won't have internet access all the time and I would therefor like to download the library you used in order to use the page 100% of the time, and how can i send arguments with the post so i know if its 'w' or 'a' or 's' or 'd' that's been pressed?

Comment: No worries, just updated answer with some instructions in the code snippet - does that help?

Comment: How do I send Arguments with HTTP post requests?

Comment: Hi just woke up, did you still need help with sending arguments?